# SETUID and SETGID Behavior

Tags: linux, chmod, chown, setuid, setgid

The setup:

```
~$ ls -l /etc/sudoers
-r--r----- 1 root root 614 2017-09-10 20:29 /etc/sudoers

~$ ls -l /etc/shadow
-rw-r----- 1 root shadow 794 2011-04-18 11:49 /etc/shadow

$ ls -l $(which ht)
-rwsr-sr-x 1 root root 2072344 2011-04-16 07:26 /usr/local/bin/ht
```

[ht](http://hte.sourceforge.net/) is a ncurses hex editor.

The question:
Why is the *ht* program able to edit `/etc/sudoers` (including saving changes), but cannot even read `/etc/shadow`?  It seems like the *ht* executable should be able to access both files based on its setuid bit and root user ownership.  Further, it seems like if edits can be saved to either file, it would be `/etc/shadow` based on the write bit for root.  However, the setgid bit is unexpectedly coming in to play.  If I change the `/etc/shadow` file *group* ownership to root (instead of shadow), I can then access it with the ht program.

Comment: I have not idea what `ht` is, but I tried the same setgid/setuid permissions on copies of `cat` and `vim` and both programs were able to read both files perfectly fine. (Vim complained about `/etc/sudoers` being read-only, of course.) On Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Interesting.  Maybe it is the ht application then.  ht is an ncurses hex editor.

Comment: What error do you get from `ht` when you try? Please update the question with the _exact_ and full error message that you get.

Comment: Hey Ben, It may be due to different group ids (ht and sudoers have same uid and gid but not ht and shadow ) I am just helping explaining behavior.  because even this is true still weird.